# Kivy Launcher orientation

Tags: python, kivy

Just a quick question:
Is it possible to enable both portrait and landscape mode in androind.txt for app run via Kivy Launcher?

I've seen that for buldozer there are "portrait/landscape/all" parameters available but it doesn't seem to work for Kivy Launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, `orientation=all` or similar thing in `android.txt` does for launcher nothing, because it maybe needs some initial orientation(?) in the beginning and rotating isn't implemented maybe?. I'd go for not implemented, because the launcher itself can rotate in all types of orientation.

However, you may try [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/) or [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/) to change/fix orientation in runtime.